# All nodes are duplicate in polygonize result

Tags: qgis, polygon, editing, error, nodes

I have a strange error with a large complex polygon shapefile (representing a hypothetical historic flood level of a lake) that I cannot resolve.  Using QGIS 2.18.14, the polygon was derived as follows...

1. Reclassify a digital elevation model (DEM) into two classes- one class above the desired flood level, one below the desired flood level.
2. Polygonize the class below the desired flood level (Raster--> Conversion--> Polygonize).
3. Subsequently, I edited the geometry of the resulting polygon to merge small islands with the larger lake level polygon.  I also adjusted some boundaries manually using the edit nodes tool.

Now, when I open the shapefile, toggle editing, and use the nodes tool, validation starts as usual, except that the entire polygon consists of duplicate nodes.  Because the polygon is large and complex (~35,000 nodes), it takes some time to validate and is really inefficient to manually inspect.  I've tried the following remedies:

- Use the GRASS v.clean tool
- Use the MMQGIS Modify--> Remove Duplicate Geometries Tool
- Import the shapefile into SAGA and convert the polygon to edges + nodes, then subsequently remove duplicate points with the Shapes - Points--> Remove Duplicate Points tool
- Export only the edges from the previous step, saving them as a polygon
  shapefile

None of these remedies seem to work.  I've not been able to find this same problem posted elsewhere online. I would ordinarily give up at this point and try to re-create the flood level polygon to better document what may have caused it to go wrong along the way (I suspect something happened during my manual editing, but I can't imagine what).  I put several hours into step 3 above (manual editing), and so it would be great if there was a way to solve this issue.

I included a link to download the shapefile below if anyone wishes to play with it.

p.s. - you may be tempted to criticize why I am even dealing with this type of analysis by converting an artificially flooded DEM into a polygon... it is a client's request to have the result as a shapefile.

[Lake polygon download](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Mj0M43qyad_cWG0oWdlpg_2Ravt2JeOu?usp=sharing)

Comment: Maybe a workaround could be to work with the raster>extract>contour tool.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to fix in QGIS 3.0. Just run the "Fix geometries" algorithm from the Processing Toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NlFLW1XMDIS_oSQnIgMmkmrNYZieRLsw). I would post how I did it, but it's an aberration of Python code mixing fiona, shapely, and gdal. Basically, I just extracted every other point vertex in your polygon shapefile. I should note that it was actually a multi-polygon and I did not preserve the smaller one--it appeared to simply overlap the northwest corner of the lake a little. Also, since I didn't check for exact duplicates, if any of your vertices did not have a duplicate, I may have removed it altogether. But it was quick and dirty.

Comment: Could you please post a solution which future readers could potentially use?

Comment: I intentionally did not post the code solution because I truly solved it in a horrendous manner due to my lack of expertise with shapely/fiona. Just a nasty, ole Frankencode from cutting and pasting off Stackexchange questions.

Answer (score 0):

It takes about 2 seconds to remove the duplicated nodes with OpenJUMP.

Use the Make Geometries Valid tool

[image]

Check the option to remove duplicate nodes

[image]

The original polygon had 79169 vertices and the processed one has 39380 so not quite every other vertex was removed.

A usual trick to simplify the geometry with tolarance of zero did not work for this geometry in OpenJUMP. You can still try if it happens to work with QGIS.